# How to create an internal store in library?

Tags: javascript

Good Day!

We are creating a library, which has multiple classes(features) and user can access the modules by `const features = new Library(/*Config*/)`. Inside the code we are fetching some APIs, whose response is needed in multiple classes. I fetched the response and saved them in an internal store explained below. (In separate module where I need store I import the path on top of file. )

**How I am doing now?**

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

class Store {
    #internalState: any

    constructor(initialState = {}) {
        this.#internalState = initialState;
    }

    get state() {
        return this.#internalState;
    }

    setState(value: any) {
        const currentState = cloneDeep(this.#internalState);
        const nextState = Object.assign(currentState, cloneDeep(value));
        this.#internalState = nextState;
        return nextState;
    }

}
console.log("called store");
export const store = new Store();
```

The problem I am facing is that when I created multiple instances of my library on same page(index.html) only single store instance is created and this class executes only once.Attached screenshot:

[image]

How can I modify my store class or any alternate approach, so that each instance have there own copy of store(Import)?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't call `new Store();` in the store module itself, call it where you want to create another instance of it. The way you currently have it implemented follows the singleton pattern. Meaning you should export the store class, not an instance of the class.

Comment: Hey @timotgl thanks for the response, yes you are correct. The problem I am facing is that I am using Facade(https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade) design pattern and I can't figure out a clean way to share the store with multiple modules. The only way I can think of is to pass the store in arguments when I initializing all modules in a single place. Any suggestions on this would be helpful.

Comment: "a clean way to share the store with multiple modules" - these modules either need to be initialized with one specific store (if they have an initialization step) or you always pass a store argument when calling their methods. The modules basically either become stateful (they use a specific store instance to save data) or they remain stateless and you need to specifiy the store for each operation. Sorry it's hard to give good advice without really knowing your entire architecture.